# Remove values in nested array of objects based on values from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I have an array of objects with the following structure:

```
let optionList = [
  {
    images: [
      {
        url: "test1"
      },
      {
        url: "test2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    images: [
      {
        url: "test3"
      },
      {
        url: "test4"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    images: [
      {
        url: "test5"
      },
      {
        url: "test6"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I also have another array called imagesToDelete with the following values:

```
 let imagesToDelete = ["test1", "test3", "test6"];
```

My goal is to **remove** **values** from the **nested array** based on the values in the **imagesToDelete** array. If done correctly, this will be the following result:

```
let optionList = [
  {
    images: [
      {
        url: "test2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    images: [
      {
        url: "test4"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    images: [
      {
        url: "test5"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Below is my current code which did not remove any values:

```
 optionList.filter(ol => {
  let result = !ol.images.some(
    image => image.url === imagesToDelete.includes(image.url)
  );
  return result;
});

console.log(optionList);
```

Comment: What do you want to do when some of the `images` array results on an empty array, for example, when  `let imagesToDelete = ["test1", "test2"];`. What is going to be the output for that case?

Comment: Hi @Shidersz In that case, the images array will be an empty array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let optionList = [{
    images: [{
        url: "test1"
      },
      {
        url: "test2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    images: [{
        url: "test3"
      },
      {
        url: "test4"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    images: [{
        url: "test5"
      },
      {
        url: "test6"
      }
    ]
  }
];
let imagesToDelete = ["test1", "test3", "test6"];
let newOptionList = optionList.map(function(option) {
  option.images = option.images.filter(function(item) {
    return !imagesToDelete.includes(item.url)
  })
  return option
})

console.log('newOptionList', newOptionList)
```

Comment: Hi @Medet Thanks for the reply! I can only accept your answer in 4 mins time. Meanwhile, is it possible if you can add some comments so that I can understand better?

Comment: You can make this shorter:
newOptionList = optionList.map(option => ({
    images: option.images.filter(image => !imagesToDelete.includes(image.url))
  }))

Comment: @VinayakBagaria we could, if we agreed on using es6, otherwise nope

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues. Mostly, you never actually modify the images array in your iterations, and filter based on the optionList which isn't actually removing any items (since if there are no images you state it is left as an empty array).

You need to iterate optionList, and modify the images array based on the list for deletion.

You can use `forEach` for the outer iteration.

```js
let optionList = [
  {
    images: [
      {
        url: "test1"
      },
      {
        url: "test2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    images: [
      {
        url: "test3"
      },
      {
        url: "test4"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    images: [
      {
        url: "test5"
      },
      {
        url: "test6"
      }
    ]
  }
];

let imagesToDelete = ["test1", "test3", "test6"];

optionList.forEach(ol => 
  ol.images = ol.images.filter(
    image => !imagesToDelete.includes(image.url)
  )
);

console.log(optionList);
```

Answer (score -1):

`filter()` returns  a new array and does not mutate original

Try doing

```js
const newList = optionList.filter(ol => {
  let result = !ol.images.some(
    image => image.url === imagesToDelete.includes(image.url)
  );
  return result;
});

console.log(newList);
```

```html
<script>
  let imagesToDelete = ["test1", "test3", "test6"];
  let optionList = [{images: [{url: "test1"},{url: "test2"}]},{images: [{url: "test3"},{url: "test4"}]},{images: [{url: "test5"},{url: "test6"}]}]
</script>
```